# Number of apache processes

Tags: apache

Looking at the below diagram which I got from [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDAQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublictopics.PublicPostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D54abb76dd11b8b811e8b45b0%26key%3D78d882ea-3897-4752-ae74-f2f850ed8f34&ei=K7YJVfiJFpO-uASe_YKgCQ&usg=AFQjCNFkuDfIRyls-xNjU1JNfb235O_GOg&sig2=koXByII52N4EVfigYyE-5A&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E):

[image: Apache process flow]

Can we make an assumption that the number of apache processes running
on the system is always at least one more than actual number of clients connected
to Apache at any time?

Comment: No, on a technicality: with worker mpm, a process handles more than one client. (Comment only as I guess you're asking about non-threaded models.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz: Well, I actually meant non-threaded models :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can generalize that as one of the points in the slide says "Apache maintains at least 5 and at most 10 inactive children at any given time"